# How to pass prop data to other components in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and I want to build a Home screen. In my Home screen, there is a date picker and a time picker as well as other components. I write the code for the date picker and the time picker in another folder and import it as props to my Homescreen like this.

```
import Datepicker from './components/Datepicker'
import Timepicker from './components/Timepicker'

export default HomeScreen() {
  return (
 <SafeAreaView>
  <Datepicker/>
  <Timepicker/>
<SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

How can I get access to the date and time variable that is declared within the Datepicker and the Timepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to look into state management: https://reactnative.dev/docs/state

But to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default HomeScreen() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [time, setTime] = useState();
  return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Datepicker setDate={setDate} />
            <Timepicker setTime={setTime} />
        <SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

And then in your individual components you can pass down the time and date respectively if you need them there, but that way the state is in the parent component and modified by the children.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of shared state. If the data and the actions that are performed on it are relatively simple, just hold them in a Context that you can use from both of the sibling components.